# Using the native SIP stack

Tags: android, compression, sip, rtp

Hi I am going to start a small project on header compression.. i will have to test it on voip..

My question is if I will be able to modify the code in the existing SIP stack (the part that probably creates the RTP packet) so that I will be able to test my ideas?

Would any1 have a better idea than using the native SIP stack?

I am new to both Android and SIP and I would really love some help on this

Answer (score 0):

Working at the application level you have only the 12 byte RTP header to compress. For a link-level solution that can work with the IP and UDP headers too you need to reach deeper, into the kernel.

But to answer your original question you also have the option to work with in-java SIP implementations predating the SIP API, like SipDroid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I came across SipDroid myself and it looks like I may be able to use the RTP implementation from that..

But if I need to make an alternative to the DatagramPacket (UDP packet) function I will have to dig into the kernel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with android, but every modern OS I know of does layer 2 (wifi or GPRS in our case), 3 (IP), and 4 (UDP) of the network stack. So I would guess yes, you'll need tor each into the kernel to provide an alternative to UDP.  While we are at it: if you are ready to dig this deep, there might be other ways to improve the mobile VoIP experience: Convince the link layer (wifi, GPRS, etc) not to waste bandwidth and time (introducing jitter) on retrasmits if the codec has FEC and graceful degradation!

Comment: Ok thanks!! I shall look into that..

I think I'll first try to implement RTP n compress that n then look into more advanced solutions.. Thanks for ur help!